# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Too many schema objects created for +kafka streams

Tags: stream, apache-kafka

I have created kafka streams project using java. The kafka streams stops and throws the below error like :

> eption: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_18,
>   processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=chil-raw, partition=18,
>   offset=414977
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:232)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.process(AssignedTasks.java:403)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:317)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:942)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:822)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)
>   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException:
>   Error serializing Avro message Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Too many schema objects created for
>   LocationGeofenceEvent-key!
>           at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:152)
>           at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:79)
>           at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
>           at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerializer.serialize(GenericAvroSerializer.java:63)
>           at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerializer.serialize(GenericAvroSerializer.java:39)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:90)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:78)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.in

I am using GenericAvroSerde and below code causing the issue . Please help me

```
@Bean
    public GenericAvroSerde genericValueSerde() {
        GenericAvroSerde serde = new GenericAvroSerde();
        serde.configure(Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url",
                properties.getSchemaRegistryUrl()), false); // XXX `false` for record values
        return serde;
    }
```